# Updating a field from an sql table from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with more columns. On one column I have 3 buttons for each row with different queries associated. When I click one of the buttons, field in the table from my database should update.The problem is that when I click on a button on any row in the table, it updates only the field from the first row.For example, I have a table with 10 rows.If I click one of the buttons on the 10th row IT will update my first row, not the 10th one as I want. Is there any possibility to solve this? 
This is the code..I'm sorry it is too long:

```
    <?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM masculin ORDER BY id_concurent";
            $result = mysqli_query($link ,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 

    if(isset($_POST['locul1']))
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE masculin SET Premiu=1 WHERE CNP='".$row['CNP']."'";      
        mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        header("Location:administrare.php");
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['locul2']))
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE masculin SET Premiu=2 WHERE CNP='".$row['CNP']."'";

         mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        header("Location:administrare.php");
    }
    else  if(isset($_POST['locul3']))
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE masculin SET Premiu=3 WHERE CNP='".$row['CNP']."'";      
        mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        header("Location:administrare.php");
    }   ?>  

<u><i><h1 align="center">Administrare concurenti</h1></i></u>
<u><i><h2>MASCULIN</h2></i></u>

<?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM masculin ORDER BY id_concurent";
            $result = mysqli_query($link ,$query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                    echo 'Inca nu s-a inscris niciun concurent.';
            } else {
        ?>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Nr.<br />concurs</th>
        <th>Nume</th>
        <th>Prenume</th>
        <th>CNP</th>
        <th>Categoria</th>
        <th>Varsta</th>
        <th>Premiu</th>
        <th>Modifica<br />rezultat</th>
        <th>Descalifica</th>
    </tr>   
      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <?php 
            $query1="SELECT id_concurent  FROM concurenti WHERE CNP='".$row['CNP']."'";
                $result1=mysqli_query($link,$query1);
                $nr_conc=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
            ?>
            <td> <?php echo $nr_conc['id_concurent'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['Nume'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['Prenume'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['CNP'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['Categorie'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['Varsta'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['Premiu'] ?> </td>         
            <td>
            <form action="administrare.php" method="post">          
                <input type="submit" name="locul1" value="Premiul 1"> 
                <input type="submit" name="locul2" value="Premiul 2"> 
                <input type="submit" name="locul3" value="Premiul 3">       
            </form>         
            </td>
        </tr>
            <?php } ?>
    </table>     <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: which is the $row['CNP']  content ???

Comment: Well, that's where I don't know what condition to write. That $row['CNP'] gets the value from the first row every time...but I need the value from the row corresponding to the buttons.. :(

Comment: i have posted  an  answer  hope is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for updated  the da tbale row when you submit  the values related  to a html table row  you should add  and hidden input with the value that let you reach the correct row eg:

```
  <form action="administrare.php" method="post">          
      <input type="submit" name="locul1" value="Premiul 1"> 
      <input type="submit" name="locul2" value="Premiul 2"> 
      <input type="submit" name="locul3" value="Premiul 3">       
      <input type="hidden" name="CNP" value="<?php echo $row['CNP'] ?>">
  </form>
```

and in your sql updated  query  add the POST value related to the row

```
  $sql = "UPDATE masculin SET Premiu=1 WHERE CNP='".$_POST['CNP']. "'";
```